# GET parameter for INT does not want to update

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, get, sql-update

```
<?php
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Content-Type");
 include_once("db_connect.php");
  if(isset($_GET["u"])){
   $username = $_GET['u'];
    } else {
    echo "No UserName";
    exit();
   }
 if(isset($_GET["v"])){
  $video= $_GET['v'];
  } else {
   echo "No Video ID";
  exit();
 }
  if(isset($_GET["like"])){
   $like = $_GET["like"];
    } else {
    echo "No Like Parameter added.";
   }
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM rating WHERE video='$video' LIMIT 1";
 $video_query = mysqli_query($db_connection, $sql);
 $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($video_query);
 if($numrows < 1){
 $sql = "INSERT INTO rating (video,username)
         VALUES ('$video','$username')";
 $video_query = mysqli_query($db_connection, $sql);
  } 

  if(isset($_GET['like'])){
   $counter = (int)$_GET["like"];
 if($counter > 5 || $counter < 1){
   echo "Rating Seems To Be Off?";
   exit();
   }
 $sql = "UPDATE rating SET like='$counter' WHERE video='$video' AND username='$username'";
 $video_query = mysqli_query($db_connection, $sql);
  echo "Voted";
 }else {
   echo "No Parameter to Vote was applied";
 exit();
 }
?>
```

Basically how I am writing the `GETs` are

?u=USERNAME&v=video0009&like=4

I want the like=4 to then update the `INT` from where the Video and Username match. Though it keeps staying at 0.

Also Keeping these as `INT` will that make it so that later I can count these together with `mysqli_fetch_assoc` ? just curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`like` is a [mysql reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) so you need to quote them using back ticks.

Replace your query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE rating SET like='$counter' WHERE video='$video' AND username='$username'";
```

with:

```
$sql = "UPDATE rating SET `like`='$counter' WHERE video='$video' AND username='$username'";
```

There are several other recommendations for your code.  First and probably the most important is SQL Injection.  Please read on [SQL Injection here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).  Have a look on how you can implement [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).  You are passing raw input directly into your database.

Comment: Oh no wonder why. ok so I will change this and see if it works. IF so thank you!

Comment: Since I am new to this all, I tried reading the SQL injection and not sure what you mean.

Comment: @EasyBB, on SQL Injection, have a read on https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet, as it describes the prevention options.

Comment: Oh so basically he is saying using `preg_replace(#[a-z0-9]#i,$_GET['u']);` to sanitize it and prevent injections? I'm not sure really if I would need mysqli_real_escape_string or is that better than preg_replace?

Comment: Stop using regular sql statements and start using prepared statements. See http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/ & http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: You could do `preg_replace` if you want to filter inputs.  A better solution would be to use prepared statements with parameterized queries using PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: @Nick New Here buddy ;) Just started like 5 days ago writing PHP lol. @Vinodadhikary thanks I'll look into PDO. I was just wondering if I could use the `preg_replace` instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string` or what is the difference really. I want to soak up all the knowledge I can ;)

Comment: If you just started, you'd better do it right the first time :P Have fun!

Comment: @Nick Reading more into your NETTUTS link I see it's PDO, And they write like `=>` which I've never done sadly. I've only used basic mysqli

Answer (score 0):

1 `like` is [mySql reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

2 your code is vulnerable to sql injection

```
$video= $_GET['v'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rating WHERE video='$video' LIMIT 1";
```

***Warning :*** you are using Mysqli it doesn't mean you eliminated  risk of Sql Injection your code is still  vulnerable to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you need to escape all `get`, `post` and `request` and the better approach will be using [Prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

**Good Read**

1. [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)